# Using AWS Amplify to authenticate Google Sign In - federatedSignin returns null?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use AWS Amplify to support email / password and Google authentication. Now, I want to store the details from Google into my user pool in AWS. I don't understand the flow here - there are many blog posts I read but most of them are just confusing.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
// gapi and Amplify included
googleSigninCallback(googleUser => {
 const googleResponse = googleUser.getAuthResponse();
 const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
 const name = profile.getName();
 const email = profile.getEmail();

 Amplify.Auth.federatedSignin('google', googleResponse, {email, name})
  .then(response => { console.log(response); }) // is always null
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

In DevTools I have the following error in the request in Network Tab:

> {"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Unauthenticated access
>   is not supported for this identity pool."}

Why should I enable unauthenticated access to this pool? I don't want to.

Am I doing this right? Is it even possible or is it a good practice to store Google User details into the AWS User Pool? If it's not a good practice, then what is?

Also, if I want to ask user for further details not provided by Google in the app and store them, how to do it if we can't store the user in User Pool?

Comment: You can't store the details from Google into the user pool without using cognito app integration. See this: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/703#issuecomment-383159143

Comment: I am facing same issue, could you solve it?

Comment: Nope. I could not.

Comment: is there any other way to do federated login between google and cognito?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your identity pool and user pool are setup for google authentication.

Then federatedSignIn has a capital last I.

And finally just change your second param in the call to federatedSignIn as follows:

```
Amplify.Auth.federatedSignIn('google', {
  token: googleResponse.id_token,
  expires_at: googleResponse.expires_at
}, {email, name})...
```